# How can I tell if a class has a method `__call__`?

Tags: python, python-3.x

A very simple class isn't a callable type:

```
>>> class myc:
...     pass
... 
>>> c=myc()
>>> callable(c)
False
```

How can I tell if a class has a method `__call__`? Why do the following two ways give opposite results?

```
>>> myc.__call__
<method-wrapper '__call__' of type object at 0x1104b18>     

>>> __call__ in myc.__dict__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name '__call__' is not defined
```

Thanks.

Comment: use try and except

Comment: `>>> '__call__' in myc.__dict__`

`False`

Comment: @bipll do I need to use quote around `__call__`?

Comment: Sure. When you quote it it's a string to be used as a dict key. When you don't quote it it is an identifier, in your case undefined yet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`myc.__call__` is giving you the `__call__` method used to call `myc` itself, not instances of `myc`. It's the method invoked when you do

```
new_myc_instance = myc()
```

not when you do

```
new_myc_instance()
```

`__call__ in myc.__dict__` gives you a NameError because you forgot to put quotation marks around `__call__`, and if you'd remembered to put quotation marks, it would have given you False because `myc.__call__` isn't found through `myc.__dict__`. It's found through `type(myc).__dict__` (a.k.a. `type.__dict__`, because `type(myc) is type`).

---

To check if `myc` has a `__call__` implementation for its instances, you could perform a manual MRO search, but `collections.abc.Callable` already implements that for you:

```
issubclass(myc, collections.abc.Callable)
```

Comment: Thanks. Whose method is `myc.__call__`? `builtins.type`'s?

Comment: @Tim: My answer now includes more detail on that.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why `myc.__call__` gives you something back <sup>1</sup> instead of raising an `AttributeError` is because the metaclass of `myc` (`type`) has a `__call__` method. And if an attribute isn't found on the instance (in this case your class) it's looked up on the class (in this case the metaclass).

For example if you had a custom metaclass the `__call__` lookup would've returned something different:

```
class mym(type):
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)

class myc(metaclass=mym):
    pass

>>> myc.__call__
<bound method mym.__call__ of <class '__main__.myc'>>
```

Regarding the `__call__ in myc.__dict__` that has been answered in the comments and the other answer already: You just forgot the quotations:

```
>>> '__call__' in myc.__dict__
False
```

However it could also be that `myc` subclasses a callable class, in that case it would also give `False`:

```
class mysc:
    def __call__(self):
        return 10

class myc(mysc):
    pass

>>> '__call__' in myc.__dict__
False
```

So you need something more robust. Like searching all the superclasses:

```
>>> any('__call__' in cls.__dict__ for cls in myc.__mro__)
True
```

Or as pointed out by user2357112 use `collections.Callable` which [overrides the `issubclass`-check](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.2/Lib/_collections_abc.py#L398-L410) so that it looks for `__call__`:

```
>>> from collections.abc import Callable
>>> issubclass(myc, Callable)
True
```

---

<sup>1</sup> That's also the reason why you can't just use `hasattr(myc, '__call__')` to find out if it has a `__call__` method itself.

Comment: Why not just `hasattr(myc, "__call__")`?

Comment: @PaulCornelius Because it would return `True` for the same reason that `myc.__call__` returns the `__call__` method of the metaclass: Because it follows the normal lookup rules. I updated the answer to include a short note about it.

Comment: Thanks. So are inherited attributes not stored in `__dict__`? what kinds of attributes are stored in `__dict__`, and what kinds not?

Comment: @Tim Yes, inherited but not-overridden attributes are not inside the `__dict__` of the subclass. The `__dict__` just contains everything you explicitly defined inside the class (or put in manually) + some special attributes like `__doc__` that Python puts in.

Comment: Thanks. what kinds of attributes does `inspect.getmembers(class)` return ?

Comment: That also includes inherited members :)

Comment: Thanks again. To test if a class `myc` has an attribute named `myattr`, can either  `'myattr' in inspect.getmembers(myc)`  or `any('myattr' in cls.__dict__ for cls in myc.__mro__)` work? Are the ways equivalent?

Comment: `inspect.getmembers` will be much slower (it's non-short-circuit and processes all `__dict__`s instead of just checking if one element is in it) and if you have a custom metaclass with `__dir__` then it will also include members of the metaclass if you call `getmembers` on a class. So in your example they will give the same result but they are by no means equivalent.

Comment: Since it include members of metaclass, if any,   is `'myattr' in inspect.getmembers(myc)` the same as `hasattr(myc, 'myattr')`?

Comment: No, those aren't the same either because `getmembers` only gives metaclass attributes that are explicitly returned in `__dir__` (source: [`inspect.getmembers` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getmembers)) while `hasattr` would find metaclass attributes unconditionally.

Comment: Thanks. What kinds of attributes are stored in `obj.__dir__`? I thought it stores exactly all the attributes accessible via `obj`, which are either the attributes of `obj`, or the attributes of the type or metaclass of `obj`?

Comment: [`__dir__`](https://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__dir__) is just a method that has a default implementation on `object` and `type`. You can override it in your class (and metaclass).

Comment: @Tim But I guess this has gotten far out of the scope of the question and answer. If you have more question you probably just ask another question about it (but check if it has been asked before).

Comment: @Tim No problem, but it's hard to really give answers in the comments. Too short (especially when including links) and no good code formatting to show examples.